# Genesis and Custom Meta Box

Tags: php, wordpress, custom-post-type

I have been using WPAlchemy for my custom meta boxes. I can usually get the meat box values to display using something like `<?php $custom_mb->the_value('summary'); ?>` but I am having trouble displaying the data in a genesis child theme. If use the above example I can get the post to display but it is at the very top of the page, even above the header. So I attempted to hook into the `genesis_post_content` hook using this

```
 add_action('genesis_post_content', 'meta_content');
function meta_content() { 
echo "Hello World";
}
```

I can echo Hello World this way but receive errors when trying the first example in the function. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I do not know Genesis and I do not use WPAlchemy ( I avoid "frameworks" like fire ) but my logic dictates that if you can see the value at the top of the page like you described ( above header ) than the method `the_value()` is doing a direct `echo`, where you would need a `return` value.

The internal wordpress core logic dictates that whenever you have an echo function ( e.g. `the_title()` ) you would potentially have an equivalent return function ( e.g. `get_the_title()` ) and it would get the same function name with an added `get_` prefix.

If the same wordpress logic is applied to those "frameworks" , or in this case to the WPAlchemy class , so instead of

`$custom_mb->the_value('summary'); // if this is direct echo`

you should be able to do :

`$custom_mb->get_the_value('summary'); // then this should be return`

Note that I did not tested it ( not using those "frameworks" , remember ?? ) but if it is indeed the case with WPAlchemy , than you would not need to invoke the genesis filter ( which by itself seems a bit wrong becasue `the_content` filter should be about the_content and not about meta_data but not knowing genesis I can not really say )